# How to distinguish sender-generated carriage returns from word wrap auto-generated carriage returns in email body?

Tags: python, email, gmail

How can I distinguish sender-generated carriage returns from word wrap auto-generated carriage returns in an email body? I'm using Python imaplib to access Gmail and download message bodies like so:

```
user='whoever@gmail.com'
pwd='password'
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
m.login(user,pwd)
m.select("INBOX")
resp, items = m.search(None, "ALL")
items = items[0].split()
messages = []
for emailid in items:
    resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)")
    email_body = data[0][1]
    mail = email.message_from_string(email_body)
    for part in mail.walk():
        if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
            body = part.get_payload(decode=1)
            messages.append(body)
```

I'm focusing on the case of messages received from another Gmail user. The message body text has a number of carriage returns ('\r\n') in it. These fall into two classes: 1) those inserted by the sender of the email, the "true" returns, 2) those created by Gmail word wrapping at ~78 characters, the "false" returns. I want to remove the second class of carriage returns only. I'm sure I could come up with a programmatic approximation that searches for the '\r\n' at a window around every 78th character but that wouldn't be bulletproof and isn't what I want. Interestingly, I notice that when the message displays in Gmail in the web browser, there are not returns for the second class of carriage returns. Gmail somehow knows to remove/not display these specifically. How? Is there some special encoding I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail sends messages in both the MIME multipart format, in both a text/plain version (what you are grabbing) and a text/html version. The latter version is what contains fancy formatting like bold, italic, links, etc., and is what Gmail displays. While the text/html version is also line-broken at 78 characters (a part of the e-mail standard -- the underlying text must never have a line exceeding 78 characters), the "real" line breaks that you are looking for are embedded therein as HTML `<br>` tags. You can see this yourself if you send yourself a message and then, using the little down-arrow next to the Reply button, click "Show original".

You cannot distinguish between "fake" and "real" line-breaks in the text/plain version of the message, at least not reliably (as you obviously know). You *can*, however, pull the text/html version instead, knowing then that the "real" line-breaks are the `<br>` tags, however you then have to deal with the additional HTML (as well as first correctly processing the "Content-Transfer-Encoding" used therein).

Comment: Thanks. I had been ignoring the text/html, that is clearly what I was looking for. When you mention correctly processing the Content-Transfer-Encoding, are you referring to anything other than using decode=True in get_payload()?

Comment: I don't actually know, I've never done anything with e-mail at all in Python, so can't speak to that. Try it, though, and just dump out whatever it gives you -- if you see a long line of text with HTML break tags, then you've got it (or long lines occasionally broken up where said HTML break tag used to be -- I don't know how much "decoding" that method would do).

Comment: OK, yeah the decoding does the trick, it prints out the stream of HTML. Now for the fun of parsing HTML. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many email clients interpret or generate this correctly, but [RFC 3676](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3676.txt) includes the following:

> When creating flowed text, the generating agent wraps, that is,
>      inserts 'soft' line breaks as needed.  Soft line breaks are added at
>      natural wrapping points, such as between words.  A soft line break is
>      a SP CRLF sequence.

So if the previous line has a space at the end of it, the current line should be interpreted as a continuation of the previous line.  I suggest reviewing the entire RFC.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the space at the end of the line gets replaced with the '\r\n', like so: 'Its a little smaller then we were looking for so we'll be tackling a master\r\nsuite addition soon after moving in.'